# anonymous variables in ocaml type inference

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I'm new to Ocaml and I've encountered a strange error when I was writing an interpreter for lambda calculus.

```
let rec valof : exp -> env -> value =
    fun exp env ->
    match exp with
      Var n -> exp2value (lookup env n)
    | Lambda (name , body) -> Clos (name , body , env) (*some thing wrong here*)
    |   _ -> Err
;;
```

`exp`, `value` and `env` are defined like:

```
type exp =
    Num of int
  | Str of string
  | Err
  | Var of string
  | Lambda of string * exp
  | App of exp * exp
;;

type value =
    Num of int
  | Str of string
  | Clos of string * exp * env
  | Err
;;

type env =
    Empty
  | Cons of string * exp * env
;;
```

When compiling, the compiler was complaining on the lambda line of the interpreter:

```
Error: This expression has type env/1490
       but an expression was expected of type env/1457
```

Any ideas where I screwed up?
Thanks!

Comment: It means that `env` was declared twice, on different lines in different scopes. The two types have the same name, but are not equal.

Comment: (Make this an answer :-)

Comment: I'll find some proper references tomorrow and then write one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: This expression has type env/1490 
but an expression was expected of type env/1457
```

This kind of error is quite frequent when you debug your code in an interactive toplevel (REPL) and it means that you declared the type `env` twice. That can happen if you are copy-pasting your code in a REPL.

---

You don't need to append all those `;;` after each statement. The OCaml compiler does not need them. Nevertheless, since `;;` meaning it is useful in the toplevel and only there.

---

As you know, the first `|` can be omitted when you are doing a pattern matching or when you are defining a sum type. However, since you want to preserve the alignment in any case it is often considered as a good practice to include the `|` on each line even if it is not an obligation.

---

Here you're type are not mutually depend but `value` depends on `exp` and `env`, and depends on `exp` that means that you have to careful declare the types in the right order. But for clarity, you might want to present them in another order that can appear more logical. (I don't mean that this order is better than another I just want you to know that you can use the following syntax).

For example, if you want to present your type top-down (from the picture thing (ie. the environment) to the internal thing (ie. values)) you can use, the `and` syntax which tells the compiler that the types depend on each other.

```
type env =
  | Empty
  | Cons of string * exp * env

and exp =
  | Num of int
  | Str of string
  | Err
  | Var of string
  | Lambda of string * exp
  | App of exp * exp

and value =
  | Num of int
  | Str of string
  | Clos of string * exp * env
  | Err
```

---

Last thing, both `value` and `exp` contain the following constructors `Num of int` and `Str of string`, OCaml can't tell if `Int 1` should be a `value` or an `exp`. More precisely, OCaml will choose that the constructor `Int` refers to `env` or `exp` (the one it will choose depends of the order in which you declared them). Thus it is advocated to choose different names for constructors.